# What does the `!!` in the `script-loader` source code mean?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I see the [`script-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader/blob/master/index.js) has one line write

```
"require(" + JSON.stringify("!!" + path.join(__dirname, "addScript.js")) + ")"
```

Who can tell me why use the `!!` here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `!` will ignore all post loaders.

Two `!!` will ignore pre and post loaders.

So if you have no `!` or only 1 `!` prefix, 
the input to your loader may 
not be the actual file because It might have been
processed by another loader 
from your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really want to post an "answer" because I don't know for sure... however, `!` is a standard webpack loader separator and that call will return something like:

```
"!!/var/www/project/addScript.js"
```

It was not present in the project's initial commits, so it stands to reason that this is a workaround that was added to be compatible with newer versions of webpack (0.9 to be exact). You can see that the first exclamation was added [here for webpack 0.9 compatibility](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader/commit/c363cd32ce0de07593f0cee3451c2a8e048e66a3). The second one was added [without much explanation (commit "Don't crash in environments without window")](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader/commit/60e7cec68d2c5ee85e11a6ec38af2da8c0d6993e)

Comment: I think I found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It just converts whatever `path.join()` returns to bool.

Comment: Because webpack can use `require('xx-loader!./file')`,I think the `!!` is a special usage.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That would only be the case if the code were: `!!path.join(__dirname, "addScript.js")`, which it is not. Sorry, but this answer is not correct.

Comment: @Rob M Can you give an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the `NormalModuleFactory.js` in the `webpack` folder.
In line 70:

```
var noPrePostAutoLoaders = /^!!/.test(request);
```

When I use `require('./file')`,the preLoader has effect on the file, and when I use `require('!!./file')`, the preLoader has no effect on the file.So, I think `!!` prefix can prevent the preLoader to affect the file or let webpack ignore the preLoader.

I found the doc in the webpack 1.x website https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#loader-order